# How to perform an action to dynamic elements within a web page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHnm9.png)I am trying to automate viewing stories on a popular social media site. What's the easiest way to click on every follower's story?

```
   while True:
      time.sleep(3)
      WebDriverWait(driver, AWAIT_PRESENCE).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TARGET_FOLLOWERS_STORIES)))
      stories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(TARGET_FOLLOWERS_STORIES)
      for story in stories:
          time.sleep(3)
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", story )
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", story)
          time.sleep(2)
          while True:
              try:
                  next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TARGET_STORIES_NEXT)))
                  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_btn)
                  time.sleep(1)
              except:
                  break
```

Answer (score 0):

As and when you click on any element in the list, the elements reference will be refreshed and selenium can not find the elements from the old list. That's the reason why you get staleElementException. You just need little tweak to the code, to handle this issue. Always get the number of stories and iterate through stories using the xpath with index <kbd>[index]</kbd>.

```
while True:
      time.sleep(3)
      WebDriverWait(driver, AWAIT_PRESENCE).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TARGET_FOLLOWERS_STORIES)))
      stories = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(TARGET_FOLLOWERS_STORIES)
      for storyNumber in range(len(stories)): #<== updated this line
          time.sleep(3)
          story = driver.find_element_by_xpath(TARGET_FOLLOWERS_STORIES + "[" +str(storyNumber+1) + "]") #<== updated this line
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", story )
          driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", story)
          time.sleep(2)
          while True:
              try:
                  next_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TARGET_STORIES_NEXT)))
                  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", next_btn)
                  time.sleep(1)
              except:
                  break
```